# How do I use bootstrap to make rows of three elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a display that looks like this with Bootstrap 4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF4lL.png, basically displaying 3 elements per row.

Elements are as follows :

```
<div class="sprite d-inline-block bg-info rounded p-1 m-1">
  <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
  <img class="sprite-img" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
  <span class="sprite-span-nickname">Text under image</span>
</div>
```

What I have right now can be seen at https://jsfiddle.net/4bmokwpe/.

How do I use Bootstrap 4 to achieve what I want ?

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/zLn5dpc9/ ?

Comment: use bootstrap-4 col to set three blocks inline.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to use bootstrap I would recommend using the existing grid-classes, "container", "row" and "col-*".

Take a look at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

This is what your markup would look like:

```css
.sprite {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sprite-span-level {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}

.sprite-img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-4">
       <div class="sprite bg-info rounded p-1 m-1">
        <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
        <img class="sprite-img" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
        <span class="sprite-span-nickname">Text under image</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4">
       <div class="sprite bg-info rounded p-1 m-1">
        <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
        <img class="sprite-img" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
        <span class="sprite-span-nickname">Text under image</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-4">
       <div class="sprite bg-info rounded p-1 m-1">
        <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
        <img class="sprite-img" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
        <span class="sprite-span-nickname">Text under image</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
       <div class="sprite bg-info rounded p-1 m-1">
        <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
        <img class="sprite-img" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
        <span class="sprite-span-nickname">Text under image</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="col-4">
       <div class="sprite bg-info rounded p-1 m-1">
        <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
        <img class="sprite-img" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
        <span class="sprite-span-nickname">Text under image</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-4">
       <div class="sprite bg-info rounded p-1 m-1">
        <span class="sprite-span-level">Top-right text over image</span>
        <img class="sprite-img" src="http://www.politicalmetaphors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blog-shapes-square-windows.jpg">
        <span class="sprite-span-nickname">Text under image</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You want something like this...?

```css
.col-wraper {
 border: 5px solid red;
 height: 100%;
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
  min-height:200px
}

.col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-4 {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
  <div class="col-wraper">
   1
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
  <div class="col-wraper">
   2
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
  <div class="col-wraper">
   3
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
  <div class="col-wraper">
   4
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
  <div class="col-wraper">
   5
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
  <div class="col-wraper">
   6
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```